# 80040111 ClassFactory cannot supply requested class (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040111 (CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE))

Tags: c++, c#-4.0, iis-7, interop, web-deployment

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0A80A563-28AE-11D3-9CD6-00C04F8B8EF1} failed due to the following error: 80040111 ClassFactory cannot supply requested class (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040111 (CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE))

I've Searched for the entry in Registry I can Find Assembly with {0A80A563-28AE-11D3-9CD6-00C04F8B8EF1} at HKLM\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID{0A80A563-28AE-11D3-9CD6-00C04F8B8EF1}\InProcServer32

I've Created Application By using embedded interop types it is working fine in the Local Machine but when i deploy it to another Server it gives the mentioned Error.

i am getting an mentioned error at following line of code

```
XYZ.IApplication Sr = new Application();
```

i have added reference to XYZ.tlb which is in C++ to my C# project.

here is the stack trace

```
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly,    Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an Issue due to Permission. IIS_User was not having permission to Access to Create Instance.

Updated Administrator Credential to App Pool and Problem was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I received the same error below.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040111): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0B92B777-B6AD-435C-B9FD-804878C36E55} failed due to the following error: 80040111 ClassFactory cannot supply requested class (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040111 (CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE)).

In my case, re-registering it several times with the following command resolved the issue.

```
regsvr32 {yourdllpath}\{yourdllfilename}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you're running the Command DOS prompt, without **Administrator** rights.

> Click START -> CMD -> Right click the Command option shown -> RUN AS
>   ADMINISTRATOR -> go to your DLL location or better still place it in
>   c:\windows\system32 or \sysWOW64 -> regsvr32 .\yourdll.dll