# Setting IIS permissions when deploying MATLAB Compiler COM Component using PHP

Tags: php, matlab, iis, com, matlab-deployment

I'm having difficulty using a COM Component in a website created using PHP running on IIS.  It looks like a permissions issue, but after a couple of days of playing with permissions I'm no closer to getting it working, so am looking for ideas.

The set up is Windows Server 2012 R2, ISS 8.0, with PHP 7.0.
The COM component is created using the MATLAB Compiler SDK R2017b.
Everything is 64-bit.

The COM component can be executed correctly from Python using,

```
import win32com.client
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("AddMatrixTestCOM.MATLABTest.1_0")
ans = obj.addmatrix(1,100,3,4)
print ans
```

Hence the COM component, and the appropriate MATLAB Component Runtime (MCR), are registered/installed correctly. (The MCR is essentially a run-time engine that is being called by the COM component.  It is comprised of various DLL's.)

To test calling a COM component from PHP I have written my own COM component (i.e. not using MATLAB).  This can be called successfully using,

```
$my_dll = new COM('SimpleAddCOM');
$outvar = $my_dll->add_ints(1, 2);
echo $outvar;
```

Hence all the appropriate php.ini setting are in place to call COM.
(The COM component is created in Visual Studio 2015, and the server has the relevant deployment libraries installed.)

However, I cannot get the following to work,

```
$my_dll = new COM('AddMatrixTestCOM.MATLABTest.1_0');
$outvar = $my_dll->addmatrix(1, 100, 3, 4);
echo $outvar;
```

An error is thrown by the first line: `Failed to create COM object 'AddMatrixTestCOM.MATLABTest.1_0': ClassFactory cannot supply requested class`

The specific error number is: 2147746065

I believe that the COM component is being found, as the error is different if I try to instantiate a component that doesn't exist, but cannot overcome (or really understand) the `cannot supply requested class` part.

I have given various Users full permissions to the directories containing the MCR and the COM component.
(Based on various Stack Overflow questions/answers with a similar topic to this, I started by giving permissions to IIS_IUSRS, then IUSR, then NETWORK SERVICES, and finally adding Everyone.
None of that worked.)

What am I missing in not being able to glue together IIS and my COM component?

**Edit**
Here's some more information:

- The `Sites` node of the IIS Manager indicates that my site uses Application Pool `mypool`.
- The table on the `Application Pools` node of the IIS Manager indicates that identity of `mypool` is `IWPD_1(myname)`
- However, if I go into the settings of `mypool` the Identity is listed as `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.  (Why are these different, and does IIS one map to the other?)

I have given `DefaultAppPool`, and `myname` and `IWPD_1(myname)` full permissions to the directories containing my COM dll and the MCR.

Anyone got anything else I can try before I give up on IIS and just go back to a linux host?

Comment: First thing is to determine with certitude what user is running your IIS worker process (should be the user that's identified in the App Pool running the IIS site). Then try to run this App Pool with, like, an admin account. Can it run (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602256/80040111-classfactory-cannot-supply-requested-class-exception-from-hresult-0x8/23498918) with an admin account? Also, is this matlab COM server a DLL or an EXE? (out-of-process)

Comment: It's an in process dll.  I'll take a look at the what user is being used, although assume (possibly incorrectly) that it's ISS_IUSRS.

Comment: The worker process is being used by `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool`, which has been given permissions to the relevant directories.  Changing to an admin account results in no change to the problem.

Comment: I don't think it's a *directory* permission issue, but more COM/AppId permission issue. How are you sure the Mathlab component is in-process, cause it really looks like it's not, especially since all works fine with your own component. Have you checked event viewer? Have you tried to create your own app pool, set the identity to an admin account, an associate this apppool with your site? also are you sure the apppool is 64bit? That can also be a Mathlab issue in this configuration

Comment: There is no doubt that everything is 64-bit.  My COM dll which calls the MATLAB MCR works fine from Python, so the MCR is working (when logged in as a local user).  My COM dll which doesn't use MATLAB works fine from the AppPool.  My suspicion is that my COM dll that requires MATLAB is being found by the AppPool, but then fails when that tries to call the MCR.  As if the AppPool user doesn't have permission to call MATLAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really answer my question, but is a work around that may help others.

I ended up changing the `Load User Profile` setting for my App Pool to `true`.  This creates a profile under `C:\Users` for the account being used by the App Pool, with appropriate permissions for the App Pool user to access.  I then installed the MATLAB MCR and located my dll's in directories within the `Documents` directory of that user profile.

I haven't yet investigated the security implications of this, but it gets me over the hump of not having any code working.